# RuntimeError: input() already active - file loop

Tags: python, loops, file-io

Read through the docs on fileinput but I'm making a basic error somewhere and I was hoping somebody could point out my mistake.

Looping through a list in a file:

```
finput = fileinput.input('file.txt')
for line in finput:
    // do something
    finput.next()
else:
    finput.close()
```

On second loop it throws

```
 raise RuntimeError, "input() already active"
```

Thought .next() was the right function to move to the second line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is raised when you try to loop over a re-opened instance of the same file returned by `fileinput.input` while the previous instance returned by `fileinput.input` is still not exhausted or closed explicitly. So, multiple instances instances of `fileinput.input` cannot be used at the same time.

From [`fileinput.input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input):

> The instance will be used as global state for the functions of this
>   module, and is also returned to use during iteration.

```
import fileinput
finput = fileinput.input('abc1')
finput.next()
finput = fileinput.input('abc1')
finput.next()
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 5, in <module>
    finput = fileinput.input('abc1')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 101, in input
    raise RuntimeError, "input() already active"
RuntimeError: input() already active
```

You can use [`fileinput.FileInput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) to use multiple instances at once. This code works fine:

```
import fileinput
finput = fileinput.FileInput('abc1')
finput.next()
finput = fileinput.FileInput('abc1')
finput.next()
```

---

Note that as @Tim Pietzcker already pointed out in his answer, the for-loop over a `fileinput` instance already returns one line at a time(in your code the variable `line` is the actual line), so,  the `.next` calls are not required there. And calling `.next` inside that loop might raise `StopIteration` error when the file object is exhausted.

```
import fileinput
finput = fileinput.input('abc1')
for line in finput:
    print line,           #current line returned by the for-loop
    print finput.next()  #Fetch the next line manually.
```

Comment: Upvoted for the "fileinput.FileInput" suggestion; just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop already iterates line by line, so calling `.next()` causes problems. Just remove that line.

```
finput = fileinput.input('file.txt')
for line in finput:
    // do something
finput.close()
```

Comment: Why would calling `.next` will cause a problem? It should simply return the next line or raise `StopIteration` error.

Comment: At the very least it will cause each other line to be skipped. Who knows what that leads to...

Comment: It doesn't leads to `RuntimeError` for sure :), checkout my answer.